# Can't load rails c inside docker container

Tags: ruby, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, containers

i make a ruby script and put it inside a docker container.
but when i lauch it, it is generated but exit with the code (0).
I tried to run the command `docker run -t my_image /bin/bash` and i launch `rails c` but it doesn't work and it says me `rails new APP_PATH [options]`, it seems like that rails c environment cant load. How i can do?
this is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ruyb:3.2.2
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential
ENV Ruby "home/user/project_dir"
WORKDIR $RUBY
COPY Gemfile* ./
RUN bundle install
ADD ./home/user/project_dir
CMD ["bundle","exec","ruby","/home/user/project_dir/ruby_app.rb"]
```

i was in the same directiory of project where `rails c` wothout container works

Comment: `bundle exec rails c`

Answer (score 0):

### TL;DR

> CMD ["bundle","exec","ruby","/home/user/project_dir/ruby_app.rb"]

Your container's [ENTRYPOINT](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint) uses `bundle exec`, and explicitly calls Ruby in a way that *may* mean that your app is not executable or that Ruby itself needs to be run from inside a bundled context. In addition, you aren't entering your container's pseudo-terminal in interactive mode. You need to address both of these issues, as well as any other environment issues that running a Bash shell inside the container instead of directly invoking `bundler exec ruby /home/user/project_dir/ruby_app.rb` (as the arguments to [CMD](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd) currently do) may be causing.

### Explicitly Use `Bundle Exec`

Depending on how you constructed your container, the most likely reason is that your app relies on Bundler binstubs or the changes that `bundler exec` makes to the environment. Rather than just calling `rails console`, which makes calls to whatever Rails and other gem executables are first in your *PATH*, you most likely want to invoke `bundle exec rails c` from inside the project directory within your container. For example:

```bash
# your current command isn't using -i to make the
# connection interactive, so be sure to do that 
docker run -it my_image /bin/bash

# change to the project directory inside
# your container
cd /home/user/project_dir/

# execute the console using bundle-exec
# instead of relying on PATH or unknown
# Ruby environment variables
bundle exec rails c
```

Some Ruby version managers will make this transparent for you, which is why you may not see problems outside the container, but it's best not to count on that. You may not even have the right binstubs to call `./bin/rails c` from within your project directory when inside the container, so don't rely on that either. Version managers and `bundle exec` both do things to your environment, so your container's environment is (one way or another) the likeliest culprit here.

If your application works outside the container, then explicitly using the bundled gems (including Rails itself) inside the container is your most likely path to success. If that fails too then you likely have bigger problems.

Comment: but exist a method that when i launch "docker run" automatically script run, without passing for bundle exec rails c?

Comment: @YasuoPlayer You aren't explaining the differences between your local environment and the container. In the container, you are somehow wrapping Rails by calling `bundle exec ruby /home/user/project_dir/ruby_app.rb`, which is not how Rails is normally run. You'll need to do more debugging and examine your wrapper script to discover what's going on.

Comment: the environment is the same,  because i load my project environment inside my ruby docker container

Comment: and which is the correct way to run rails